# ValueError: Expected object or value while reading JSON using Pandas with Chunksize and lines=True

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've looked into mutliple stackoverflow threads and pandas document but I am still getting following error when trying to read json as below

**source:** `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-json-reader` and section `Line delimited json`

```
import pandas as pd
chunks = pd.read_json('/Users/abc/PycharmProjects/test-json/records1.json', lines=True, chunksize=10)

for chunk in chunks:
    print(chunk)
    break
```

**error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abc/PycharmProjects/abc_code/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/Users/abc/.local/share/virtualenvs/abc_code-bU7zXpdS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 744, in __next__
    obj = self._get_object_parser(lines_json)
  File "/Users/abc/.local/share/virtualenvs/abc_code-bU7zXpdS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 716, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
  File "/Users/abc/.local/share/virtualenvs/abc_code-bU7zXpdS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 831, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()
  File "/Users/abc/.local/share/virtualenvs/abc_code-bU7zXpdS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 1079, in _parse_no_numpy
    loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
**ValueError: Expected object or value**
```

PS:

- It works fine if I read without `lines=True, chunksize=10` params but isn't working with these params. reason I am using these params is because we get big jsons and I don't want to load all of that in memory in single go.
- For testing purpose, let's say I want to filter people from this json for whom  `"isActive": true`.
- I am using `python v3.7.9 and pandas v1.3.1`

thanks for the help!!

For reference, please find below the sample snippet of json which I am trying to read

```
[{
    "_id": "5c21a63a1e4bb8d6a7d1ffa0",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "ae4d6f3d-ad3f-4923-8b87-8456d427f96e",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,624.10",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 30,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": {
        "first": "Alvarado",
        "last": "Castro"
    },
    "company": "ARTWORLDS",
    "email": "alvarado.castro@artworlds.com",
    "phone": "+1 (937) 418-3892",
    "address": "190 Joralemon Street, Talpa, Hawaii, 4597",
    "about": "Veniam ut officia exercitation eiusmod officia nulla id est consectetur. Laboris excepteur id dolore consequat dolore ad deserunt anim anim. Eu ea ad cupidatat consequat duis id ut elit adipisicing ea minim irure ullamco voluptate. Irure reprehenderit duis esse esse dolore voluptate ad. Reprehenderit veniam qui velit cupidatat. Veniam consectetur aliquip quis sit laboris sint adipisicing occaecat occaecat consequat sint.",
    "registered": "Friday, October 5, 2018 6:26 PM",
    "latitude": "-59.473097",
    "longitude": "118.295711",
    "tags": [
        "adipisicing",
        "incididunt",
        "deserunt",
        "commodo",
        "nisi"
    ],
    "range": [
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9
    ],
    "friends": [{
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Mcgee Delacruz"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Marquita Robinson"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Mullen Foreman"
        }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Alvarado! You have 7 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
}]
```

Comment: thats exactly the same problem I have.